# ReactiveX First operator with condition in rx-android

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm new to reactiveX. I've included rx-android in my project by adding to my gradle module file these lines:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
```

and now I'm trying to start using it. As a first attempt, I'm trying to use reactiveX to check if two lists contains at least a common element. I've created an observable from the first list and then I want to test each element against the list of element contained in the second list. I've successfully implemented the operation this way

```
public boolean hasAnyType(TYPE[] types){
    Observable<TYPE> o = Observable.fromArray(types);
    return !o.filter(type -> hasType(type)).isEmpty().blockingGet();
}
```

But, if I've understood correctly, the `filter` operator tests all the elements generated by the obervable while I just want to know if a match is found. It is useless to iterate over all the element when a match is found.
I've seen the operator [`first`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) that should do exactly what I need

> emit only the first item (or the first item that meets some condition) emitted by an Observable

Trying to use it in my Android project, it looks like the conditional version of the operator is not available in the library. Is it true? is there a way to have it in rx-android? If not which would be the right reactive approach to the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: plz put your observable code so we can help you implement the filter operator

Comment: Have you looked at [any(Predicate)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#any-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-)?

Comment: So your observable did not emit anything and stop at first emission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770025/reactivex-first-operator-with-condition-in-rx-android?noredirect=1#comment82503406_47770025)! The `any` operator works perfectly. My final code is

```
public boolean hasAnyType(TYPE[] types){
    Observable<TYPE> o = Observable.fromArray(types);
    return o.any(this::hasType).blockingGet();
}
```

For the sake of completeness, I've tested my previous implementation and, even if the one proposed by akarnokd is much better, it works the same way. The test is repeated until a result is found then the result is returned without testing any other element.